# Angular 2+ Multiple Select: Change UI to Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have designed a multi-select dropdown UI/UX and created in it jQuery. The project I am working on is built in Angular and my peer converted my jQuery into Angular.

Angular requires the multiple attribute for multi-select yet it changes the UI/UX.  It's no longer a drop down.

Here is the code for the html for this multi-select

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="document.category" id="MySelect" name="category" #category="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="addCategory($event)"multiple required>
```

ANyone know how to convert the UI/UX back into a dropdown without removing the multiple attribute?

Comment: There is a very high likelihood (like 100%) you did not use a `<select>` element as the primary UI for your jQuery solution. Yet in the Angular version you are. Can you please provide the differences so we are better prepared to help?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the Angular docs... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

If you have multiple options I would recommend looking at using ng-repeat on the `<option>` element

Comment: Thank you ... the html code I used before was the same (using select) except I did not insert the multiple attribute.  When I take that attribute out the UI reverts back to a dropdown, but the app no longer remembers the user's selection.

Comment: Thanks Kyle too!  Weird just adding the multiple attribute changes the UI/UX as seen here https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview  (just add the multiple attribute in the select and the dropdown no longer exists..it goes to a multi-select view).  Is that being driven by CSS as Inspected the Element thoroughly and wasn't able to fully figure out if it's a CSS thing or not.